# How to add security (username, password) to grails cxf web service

Tags: web-services, security, grails, cxf

I created two grails project, one for server side cxf web service and other for cxf client for calling web service..

Everything works fine.

I can call web service from client code and get result.

Now I want to add security, then what will be the changes to server and client grails code?

I tried applying security as said by Christian Oestreich in his post.

http://www.christianoestreich.com/2012/04/grails-cxf-interceptor-injection/
(Grails Cxf Interceptor Injection 2.4.x-2.5.x)

and client code for applying security is as follows

```
    ExampleService exampleService = new ExampleService()
    def port = exampleService.exampleServicePort
    Map ctx = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
    ctx.put("ws-security.username", "pankaj");
    ctx.put("ws-security.password", "pankaj");
    println ".......... " + port.sayHello("pankaj")
```

But I am getting error as follows

```
Error |
2014-11-06 18:33:15,411 [http-bio-8088-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SoapFault occurred when processing request: [GET] /WSDLDemoClient/wsdldemo/index
An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header.
Line | Method
->>   75 | unmarshalFault         in org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of above mentioned client code, use following code to get it working.

```
    Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider)hello).getRequestContext();
    req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, WS_URL);

    Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    headers.put("Username", Collections.singletonList("pankaj"));
    headers.put("Password", Collections.singletonList("pankaj"));
    req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```